# Why are finite Coxeter groups always tame, why are infinite tame Coxeter groups integral

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

According to Lusztig's *[Hecke Algebras with Unequal Parameters](http://books.google.com.hk/books?id=qvbcnNZo9XgC&pg=PA16&lpg=PA16&dq=finite%20coxeter%20groups%20are%20tame&source=bl&ots=CpD7V1rWYT&sig=qN53j6HEMcsDbKD3MPbB1HBkKYw&hl=zh-CN&sa=X&ei=kkEwUe_0MsSwiQfQrYHABw&ved=0CHsQ6AEwCQ#v=onepage&q=finite%20coxeter%20groups%20are%20tame&f=false)* (also available as [arXiv preprint math/0208154v1](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0208154v1)):

**Coxeter group**. Let $S$ be a finite set, and for any $s,s' \in S$, $m_{s,s'}$ be a positive integer or $\infty$. Assume that $m_{s,s} = 1$ for every $s \in S$. Assume also that $m_{s,s'} = m_{s',s} > 1$ for any two distinct elements $s$ and $s'$ of $S$. A Coxeter group $(W,S)$ is a group with generator set $S$ and relations $(ss')^{m_{s,s'}} =1$.

Let $(W,S)$ be a Coxeter group, $E$ be an $\mathbb R$-vector space with basis $(e_s)_{s \in S}$. Define a symmetric $\mathbb R$-bilinear form
$$(,): E \times E \rightarrow \mathbb R, (e_s, e_{s'}) \mapsto -\cos \pi/m_{s,s'}.$$

$W$ is said to be **tame** if $(e,e) \geq 0$ for any $e \in E$; **integral** if for any $s,s' \in S$, we have $4 \cos^2 \pi/m_{s,s'} \in \mathbb N$, or equivalently, $m_{s,s'} = \{ 2,3,4,6, \infty \}$.

Then Lusztig states that

> 1. if $W$ is finite, then it is tame.
> 2. if $W$ is tame and infinite, then it is automatically integral.

I don't why. Please give me some help on proving it. Thanks.

Comment: I would guess that you are not expected to prove this yourself at this point. Are you familiar with the classification of finite groups generated by reflections? Some hopefully relevant concepts are [Coxeter groups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coxeter_group), [root systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_system), [affine Lie algebras](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_Lie_algebra)

Comment: As Jyrki said, this is not an exercise. It's indeed classical theory, and can be found in classical textbooks on Coxeter books, especially (1) on the classification of finite Coxeter groups: (1) is in Bourbaki, Lie groups and Lie algebras. (2) concerns the classification of affine Coxeter groups and references should be easy to find.